# Underline sentences in UITextView by touch

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, object, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have implemented a UITextView where i can underline the text, sometime the text is not underlined at the right place it crosses the words and sentences, is there a default method which underlines the sentences at the right places avoiding the user to maintain the accuracy while touching the screen. help greatly appreciate please share your views.

Comment: I recommend to use Core Text for this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `UITextView` with attributed text and modify the attributes as needed.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"All work an no play makes Jack a dull boy."];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) range:NSMakeRange(15, 4)];
self.textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

where `self.textView` is an `IBOutlet` to your `UITextView` and the values are the `NSRange` are determined by your user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that internally a UITextView is a UIWebDocumentView (aka WebKit) and HTML has different rules for underlining words than normal text editors. See my analysis here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/12/uitextview-caught-with-trousers-down/

The approach to set the attributedString the the problem that you would only be able to set the entire text.

Since we do not have direct access at the text container inside UIWebDocumentView and because of the intricacies of HTML you cannot hope to achieve a perfect result.

You can only solve this problem by rendering the text yourself with CoreText. My open source component DTCoreText could help with the display. I am also selling a commercial component for rich text editing that is based on that: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/12/dtrichtexteditor-1-1/

PS: he standard method for toggling the currently selected range of text underlined is `toggleUnderline:` defined as such:

```
@interface NSObject(UIResponderStandardEditActions)   // these methods are not implemented in NSObject

- (void)cut:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
- (void)copy:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
- (void)paste:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
- (void)select:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
- (void)selectAll:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
- (void)delete:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_2);
- (void)makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (void)makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (void)toggleBoldface:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (void)toggleItalics:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (void)toggleUnderline:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

@end
```

This is exactly what the context menu adds if you enable attribute editing. If you are not happy with the result here, then my above statements are the way to go.